# Cannot Query the SnowFlake Database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

I am getting the Below Error when trying to Query a table in SnowFlake using the tSnowFlakeInput component in Talend Open Studio 8.0 with SnowFlake JDBC 3.13.1 in Talend Open Studio 7.3 with SnowFlake JDBC 3.11 I don't get any error,

Please help

```
[WARN ] 16:11:35 org.talend.components.api.component.runtime.JarRuntimeInfo- Unable to make field private static volatile java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory java.net.URL.factory accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @635eaaf1

Jul 10, 2023 4:11:44 PM net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeChunkDownloader getNextChunkToConsume

SEVERE: downloader encountered error: Max retry reached for the download of # chunk0 (Total chunks: 1) retry=10, error=net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLLoggedException: JDBC driver internal error: Exception: sun.misc.Unsafe or java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int) not available.
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeChunkDownloader$2.downloadAndParseChunk(SnowflakeChunkDownloader.java:899)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeChunkDownloader$2.call(SnowflakeChunkDownloader.java:954)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeChunkDownloader$2.call(SnowflakeChunkDownloader.java:770)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: sun.misc.Unsafe or java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int) not available
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.directBuffer(PlatformDependent.java:399)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.NettyArrowBuf.getDirectBuffer(NettyArrowBuf.java:243)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.NettyArrowBuf.nioBuffer(NettyArrowBuf.java:233)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.ArrowBuf.nioBuffer(ArrowBuf.java:247)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ReadChannel.readFully(ReadChannel.java:81)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.readMessageBody(MessageSerializer.java:696)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageChannelReader.readNext(MessageChannelReader.java:68)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowStreamReader.loadNextBatch(ArrowStreamReader.java:106)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.ArrowResultChunk.readArrowStream(ArrowResultChunk.java:78)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeChunkDownloader$2.downloadAndParseChunk(SnowflakeChunkDownloader.java:883)

... 6 more

Exception in component tDBInput_1 (Test_Job)

java.io.IOException: Error processing query: SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE

LIMIT 10
at org.talend.components.snowflake.runtime.SnowflakeReader.start(SnowflakeReader.java:138)
at org.talend.codegen.flowvariables.runtime.FlowVariablesReader.start(FlowVariablesReader.java:73)
at my_test_proj.test_job_0_1.Test_Job.tDBInput_1Process(Test_Job.java:15208)
at my_test_proj.test_job_0_1.Test_Job.tDBConnection_1Process(Test_Job.java:535)
at my_test_proj.test_job_0_1.Test_Job.runJobInTOS(Test_Job.java:16553)
at my_test_proj.test_job_0_1.Test_Job.main(Test_Job.java:16391)

Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLLoggedException: JDBC driver internal error: Max retry reached for the download of # chunk0 (Total chunks: 1) retry=10, error=net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLLoggedException: JDBC driver internal error: Exception: sun.misc.Unsafe or java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int) not available.
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeChunkDownloader$2.downloadAndParseChunk(SnowflakeChunkDownloader.java:899)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeChunkDownloader$2.call(SnowflakeChunkDownloader.java:954)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeChunkDownloader$2.call(SnowflakeChunkDownloader.java:770)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: sun.misc.Unsafe or java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int) not available
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.directBuffer(PlatformDependent.java:399)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.NettyArrowBuf.getDirectBuffer(NettyArrowBuf.java:243)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.NettyArrowBuf.nioBuffer(NettyArrowBuf.java:233)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.io.netty.buffer.ArrowBuf.nioBuffer(ArrowBuf.java:247)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ReadChannel.readFully(ReadChannel.java:81)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.readMessageBody(MessageSerializer.java:696)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageChannelReader.readNext(MessageChannelReader.java:68)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowStreamReader.loadNextBatch(ArrowStreamReader.java:106)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.ArrowResultChunk.readArrowStream(ArrowResultChunk.java:78)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeChunkDownloader$2.downloadAndParseChunk(SnowflakeChunkDownloader.java:883)

... 6 more

.
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeChunkDownloader.getNextChunkToConsume(SnowflakeChunkDownloader.java:518)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFArrowResultSet.fetchNextRowUnsorted(SFArrowResultSet.java:233)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFArrowResultSet.fetchNextRow(SFArrowResultSet.java:210)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFArrowResultSet.next(SFArrowResultSet.java:346)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeResultSetV1.next(SnowflakeResultSetV1.java:99)
at org.talend.components.snowflake.runtime.SnowflakeReader.haveNext(SnowflakeReader.java:144)
at org.talend.components.snowflake.runtime.SnowflakeReader.start(SnowflakeReader.java:136)

... 5 more
```

Comment: JDBC 3.13.33 seems to be the latest version - why not try that?

Answer (score 0):

I was using JDK 20 to run Talend 8.0 that was causing the problem, On using JDK 11 Solved the issue